# What is a suitable compression algorithm for a large set of UTF-16 strings(multilingual)?

Tags: utf-16, wstring, lossless-compression

I need to compress a large number of short multilingual strings(<1000bytes each). I have tried implementing LZW with a separate dictionary for each language. Is there a better solution for this? The strings are stored in a set so the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Try to convert them to UTF-8 first. Together with LZW, that might yield even better compression. You can easily convert them back to UTF-16 after decompression. Most LZW algorithms produce a header at the start that can be shortened. For short strings, this might make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 library to create encoded binary represantation + zlib compression might help.

Comment: Why use Base64? When using a standard compression method, such as zlib, the effect of an additional recoding shouldn't make a difference at all (since Base64 neither adds nor removes entrophy)

Comment: That's actually true an thanks for pointing out. It actually adds some entropy by additional recording;                                                                                                                                           ------           text = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG."
print(sys.getsizeof(zlib.compress(text.encode('utf16')))) -> 104 Bytes
print(sys.getsizeof(zlib.compress(base64.b64encode(text.encode('utf16'))))) - 127 Bytes
print(sys.getsizeof(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text.encode('utf16'))))) - 129 Bytes